# Randomly dividing a list into chunks of two or three items

Tags: python, list, random, chunks

I am stuck on a problem involving splitting up a list into different sized chunks. I want to have a list that is randomly split into either pairs of 2 or 3.

example:

```
L = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

and I want to get something out like:

```
L2 = [(1,1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1)]
```

but this I want to be random, so that the distribution of pairs and triplets changes everytime the code is ran.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to split a list into randomly sized chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439011/best-way-to-split-a-list-into-randomly-sized-chunks)

Comment: The answers there are quite elegant. But for this specific case, they sometimes lead to a chunk containing 1 element when the list can be split into multiples of 2s and 3s alone.

For ex : The accepted answer there gave `[[1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1]]` for L2 in one of the iterations when run with `min_chunk=2` and `maxchunk=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more general approach you can use following function:

```
from itertools import count
import random
def my_split(lst, chunks):
    def chunk_creator():
        total = 0
        while total <= len(lst):
            x = random.choice(chunks)
            yield L[total: x + total]
            total += x
        yield total - x

    def chunk_finder():
        for _ in count():
            chunk = list(chunk_creator())
            total = chunk.pop(-1)
            if total == len(L):
                return chunk[:-1]
    if max(chunks) <= len(L):
        return chunk_finder()
    else:
        return None
```

Demo :

```
>>> L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
>>> my_split(L, (2, 3))
... [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> my_split(L, (2, 3))
... [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

## Explanation:

This function is consist of to sub functions. First one is chunk_creator which it's job is creating the desire chunks based on the length of your list and return them as an iterator. Note that, the end value is the `total` variable which is the sum of preceding chunks.

The second function (`chunk_finder`) will find the desire chunks for us by goring through an in infinity loop (`itertools.count()`) and checking if the value of `total` is equal with the length of input list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, maybe you can write a generator that returns chunks of sizes based on a `size` function:

```
import random

def take_chunked(i, size):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(i):
        s = size(i[idx:])
        yield i[idx:idx+s]
        idx += s

def size_fun(i):
    if len(i) == 4:
        return 2
    if len(i) <= 3:
        return len(i)

    return random.randint(2,3)
```

Output:

```
>>> list(take_chunked("helloworld", size_fun))
['he', 'll', 'owo', 'rld']
>>> list(take_chunked("helloworld", size_fun))
['hel', 'low', 'or', 'ld']
>>> list(take_chunked("a", size_fun))
['a']
>>> list(take_chunked("", size_fun))
[]
```

This version will guarantee that the chunk sizes are either 2 or 3, as long as there are enough items in the list.

Comment: Yes I added a comment about that.

Comment: Updated to fix that, with a less elegant `size_fun`

Answer (score 0):

Factorize `len(L)` into chunks of 2s and 3s and then use a loop to divide the list.

```
import numpy as np

def rand23():
    return np.random.randint(2,4)

def get_chunk(sz):
    rem = sz
    ch = []
    while ( rem > 0 ):
        if ( rem <= 3 ): #if <= 3 add what is left in the chunk (exit condition)
            ch.append(rem)
            rem = 0
            break
        elif ( rem == 4 ): #4 is the only edge case here
            ch.append(2)
            ch.append(2)
            rem = 0
            break
        else:
            ch.append(rand23())
            rem -= ch[-1]

    return ch

L = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
ch = get_chunk(len(L))
L2 = []
count = 0
#Divide the list into chunks based on ch
for c in ch:
    L2.append(tuple(L[count:count+c]))
    count += c

print L2
```

Results:( each line is output of an iteration )

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]

[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]

[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]

[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1)]

[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]

[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]

[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

PS : You can also implement `get_chunk()` recursively.

Comment: This would always give the same result. OP asked for a random sequence of pairs and triples.

Comment: Yeah. realized that a bit later. correcting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

step1: use random module to generate a random number

step2: use random number to decide if it should be pair or 2(for even random number)/3(if random is nt even).

step3: code it.

```
from random import random

def selector():
    s = int(random() * 100 )
    return (s/2) == 0

L = [1 for i in range(30)]
L2 = []

while L:
    if selector():
        tmp = 2
    else:
        tmp = 3
    #print tmp
    if tmp > 0 and len(L) >= tmp:
        L2.append( [ L.pop() for i in range(tmp)] )
    if len(L) < 3:
        L2.append(set(L))
        L = []

print L, L2
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is fairly simple and will do the trick :-)

```
import random

L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
L2 = list()

i = 0
j = random.randint(2, 3)

while i < len(L):
    chunk = L[i:j]
    L2.append(chunk)
    i = j
    if len(L) - i == 4:  # case: 4 elements left in L
        j = i + 2
    elif len(L) - i < 4:  # case: 2 or 3 elements left in L
        j = len(L)
    else:
        j = i + random.randint(2, 3)

print L
print L2
```