# Draw specified number of sample from list. Use all list elements

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list of elements. Now I want to specify the number of draws/samples I take from this list. However, I must ensure that

(i) all samples together include all original elements

(ii) the sample sizes should not be the same for each sample

> **One update to my original question**
>
> **UPDATE** (iii) the minimum sample size is 2

Example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
draws = 4
samples = some_function(draws,list)
set(tuple(row) for row in sample) == set(list) # must be true
```

`samples =[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10]]` # 4 draws, together include all elements, two different sample sizes, minimum sample size > 2

**Question:** is there an easy way to do this using e.g. `numpy.random`?**

Here is one attempt using `np.random.permutation` and `np.random.choice`. However, this approach does not always have all list elements in the final samples.

```
srch_list = list(range(100))
draws = 10
mid = round(len(srch_list)/draws)
n_leafs = range(mid-2,mid+3)

rnd_list = np.random.permutation(srch_list)
leafs = []
for i in range(draws):
    idx = np.random.choice(n_leafs)
    leafs.append(rnd_list[:idx])
    rnd_list = rnd_list[idx:]
```

Comment: You may find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439011/best-way-to-split-a-list-into-randomly-sized-chunks

Comment: Thx. Took a look. However, I need to specify the number of samples. This is not covered in your link. But: a combination of the solution of your link and the one below would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

ids = np.concatenate(([0],
                     np.random.choice(range(1, len(l)-1), 3, replace=False),
                     [len(l)]))

ids = np.sort(ids)

chunks = [l[i:j] for i,j in zip(ids[:-1], ids[1:])]

chunks
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Now if you also need to shuffle elements of the list you can use [numpy.random.shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

```py
np.random.shuffle(l)
chunks = [l[i:j] for i,j in zip(ids[:-1], ids[1:])]

chunks
[[5, 9], [3], [10, 1, 6, 8, 7], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! Follow up question: could I extend your example so that I can define what the min and max sample sizes can be?

Comment: I have updated my question. How would I ensure that the minimum sample size is > 1?

Comment: Maybe this is not the best approach to ensure that each chunk has a size of at least 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
import numpy as np


def draw_samples(pool, nsamples, min_sample_size=1):
    # make sure pool is an array for the logic to work
    if not isinstance(pool, np.ndarray):
        pool = np.array(pool)

    # fist determine the total amount of samples to be drawn from pool
    min_total_n_elements = len(pool) if len(pool) > nsamples*min_sample_size \
        else nsamples*min_sample_size
    max_total_n_elements = min_total_n_elements + 5  # the sky is the limit
    total_n_elements = np.random.randint(
        min_total_n_elements, max_total_n_elements
    )
    additional_n_elements = total_n_elements - min_total_n_elements

    # then extend the pool the samples are going to be drawn from
    extended_pool = np.append(
        pool, np.random.choice(pool, size=additional_n_elements)
    ) if additional_n_elements else pool

    # assign each element in the pool to a sample
    assignment = np.array(list(np.arange(nsamples))*min_sample_size)
    if total_n_elements - len(assignment):
        assignment = np.append(
            assignment, np.random.choice(
                np.arange(nsamples), size=total_n_elements - len(assignment)
            )
        )
    np.random.shuffle(assignment)
    samples = [extended_pool[assignment == i] for i in range(nsamples)]

    return samples


lst = np.arange(10)
n_subsamples = 4
samples = draw_samples(lst, n_subsamples, min_sample_size=2)
print(set.union(*[set(sample) for sample in samples]) == set(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks. This does'n always work, though. Some samples are empty lists. I have updated my question. How would I ensure that the minimum sample size is > 1?

Comment: Well that changes quite a lot

Comment: Thanks. I have meanwhile found a solution based on the other proposed solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first answer (by `FBruzzesi`) I came up with the following solution:

```
def _sample_leaf_combinations(l:list,draws=10, minchunk=2):

    ldraw = list(range(minchunk,len(l)-1)[::minchunk])[:-1] # list to draw indices from. Note: deletes some items in order to ensure that distance between indices is at least minchunk
    if len(ldraw) <= draws -1:
        raise ValueError(f"Cannot make {draws} draws from list of {len(l)} with minchunk of {minchunk}. Consider lowering minchunk")


    ids = np.concatenate(([0],np.random.choice(ldraw, draws-1, replace=False),[len(l)]))
    ids = np.sort(ids)
    chunks = [l[i:j] for i,j in zip(ids[:-1], ids[1:])]

    return chunks
```

Thanks for your help!